# CSS not loading in localhost

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, localhost

It was working previously but I can't pinpoint where the source of the problem is.

I'm importing my `styles.css` folder with index.js. I swapped some JS code around, the problem happened, and after getting nowhere I reverted my code back to the way it was. But for some reason the problem still persists.

I wondered if some of my dependencies were conflicting with another, but now that I've disabled most of them I don't think they're related to the CSS not working. I've also scanned over `styles.css` and as far as I can tell there aren't any missing braces or errors.

When I compile my code via webpack and upload it to SharePoint the CSS does load, so there's something off about what I'm working with locally.

Any thoughts? I can't proceed with my project unless I can get the CSS back. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD8lz.png) of my browser and here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgupz0Le/) of my `webpack.config.js`.

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <head>
    <title>Training Library</title>

  <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"> --><!-- due to ./styles.css being imported via index.js I'm not sure if this line is needed -->
  </head>
  <body>
```

#### index.js

```
import "./styles.css";
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
// import 'jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css';
// import './SiteAssets/plugins/jquery-ui.min.css';

import 'jquery';

// import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
// import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js';
// import './SiteAssets/plugins/jquery.autocomplete.js';

// import './SiteAssets/plugins/moment.min.js';

import TopCoursesComponent from './SiteAssets/scripts/topCourses';
import NewCoursesComponent from './SiteAssets/scripts/newCourses';
import AllCoursesComponent from './SiteAssets/scripts/allCourses';
```

#### File structure:

```
+ TrainingLib
 + dist
 + node_modules
 + public
  - index.html
 + src
  + SiteAssets
   + plugins
   + scripts
    - allCourses.js
    - newCourses.js
    - etc
  - index.js
  - styles.css
 - package.json
 - webpack.config.js
```

Comment: try giving `import "./styles.css";` a full path to the CSS file. I *think* Webpack is interpreting that correctly but your local server isn't...

Comment: Thanks Bryce, I'll give it a shot when I get home. If the server isn't interpreting it correctly, any thoughts as to why?

Comment: It typically has to do with what the server calls "root". Webpack translates that into something. What are you using to host? Is it an NPM script of some kind? Your issue is backward from what I usually expect. (local usually gets it right and it breaks in build or prod)